# How to workaround error `&'static str` is forbidden as the type of a const generic parameter?

Tags: rust, const-generics

I'm implementing an RPC system (the following code is simplified for illustration, it cannot be compiled, for a fully runnable example, please see [this playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=660a9ecc9c746c72df6ccbd9fb9e5d13)):

```
trait RpcHandler<Req> {
    fn handle(&self, req: Req);
}

struct CommonRequest;

struct MyStruct;

impl RpcHandler<CommonRequest> for MyStruct {
    fn handle(&self, req: CommonRequest) {
        let rpc_method_name = get_rpc_method_name_from_rpc_context();
        match rpc_method_name {
            "foo" => self.foo(req),
            "bar" => self.bar(req),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}

type HandlerMap = HashMap<String, Box<dyn RpcHandler>>;
static HANDLERS: HandlerMap;

fn register_rpc<Req>(method_name: &str, handler: &impl RpcHandler<Req>) {
    HANDLERS.insert(method_name, Box::new(handler));
}

fn on_rpc_call(buf: &[u8]) {
    let rpc_method_name: &str = decode_method_name_from_bytes(buf);
    let req = decode_request_struct_from_bytes(buf);
    let handler = HANDLERS.get(rpc_method_name).unwrap();
    handler.handle(req);
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct;
    register_rpc("foo", &s);
    register_rpc("bar", &s);

    let buf: Vec<u8> = recv_some_bytes_from_network();
    on_rpc_call(&buf);
}
```

As you can see, I have actually two RPC methods `foo` and `bar` for `MyStruct`, both methods are registered as dynamic handlers. When a request is received, I decode the method name and request body from that, and find the proper handler by name, and then call that handler with decoded request body.

However, `foo` and `bar` share a same request type `CommonRequest`, so I can **ONLY** implement `RpcHandler<CommonRequest>` for `MyStruct` **ONCE**, so I have to write the code of `foo` and `bar` in the same implementation of `RpcHandler<CommonRequest>`. I think the more idiomatic way should be adding RPC method name to the trait, so I can implement `RpcHandler` for each RPC method (and request type) on `MyStruct`:

```
trait RpcHandler<const RpcMethodName: &'static str, Req> {
    fn handle(&self, req: Req);
}

impl RpcHandler<"foo", CommonRequest> for MyStruct {
    fn handle(&self, req: CommonRequest) {
        self.foo(req);
    }
}

impl RpcHandler<"bar", CommonRequest> for MyStruct {
    fn handle(&self, req: CommonRequest) {
        self.bar(req);
    }
}
```

However, the compiler complains that `&'static str` is forbidden as the type of a const generic parameter, any idiomatic/elegant workaround of that? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. In your first example, where does `rpc_method_name` come from? It looks like a run-time value, so I can't se how you'd use it as a const generic parameter even if that was possible.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Maybe having a `trait` with a `const` could work instead? So `trait Name { const NAME: &'static str; }` then instead of `const Name: &'static str`, use `N: Name`. But it very much depends on what the source of that string is, and what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @SvenMarnach Sorry for the unclear description, I posted a full example, please see the link in "EDIT" section.

Comment: @vallentin Sorry for the unclear description, I posted a full example, please see the link in "EDIT" section.

Comment: Like @SvenMarnach said, how are you going to dispatch on the name (a runtime value) based on const generics (a compile-time value) without enumerating all possibilities, which you can (and already) do without const generics? In other words, how will const generics benefit you?

Comment: @cafce25 Thanks for your kind reminder, I have totally re-edited the question. However, the fully working code piece is too large and contains quite a lot things not related to this question, so I still simplified the code for illustration, and posted a link to the fully working example, hope it did not violate the rules.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I have re-edited my question, actually the dispatch is based on runtime method names and trait objects. I use const generics not for the dispatch, but for trait implementation limitation: I want to implement `RpcHandler<CommonRequest>` for `foo` and `bar` twice on `MyStruct`, but currently it's only allowed to implement once.

Comment: Does this do what you want: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4cad1a3685c120ab673023c1ad43446?

Comment: You could even just use a unit struct as a type parameter instead of the string parameter.

Comment: Const generics won't help you as you will need to specify them in `dyn Trait`, preventing polymorphism. You will have to wrap the existing struct in a newtype.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks for the code snippet, yeah, it's kind like that, however, I need to figure out how to associate the `FOO`/`BAR` integers to "foo"/"bar" strings, maybe I can make a map for that.

Comment: @cdhowie Yes, I have thought about that, however, how to associate each unit struct type to corresponding string? e.g. `struct Foo;` to string `"foo"`?

Comment: @KelvinHu Create a trait like `trait RouteName { fn route_name() -> &'static str; }` and implement it on the struct.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks, I get your point, that's brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler forbids `&str` as a `const` generic, but I don't think it would actually help in your situation. Even if you used `i32`, which is allowed, you would need to make the actual call like so:

```rust
trait RpcHandler<const Name: i32, Req> {
    fn handle(&self, req: Req);
}

// here `1` is used for the `const Name` type parameter
<MyStruct as RpcHandler<1, _>>::handle(&x, 0);
```

But this is a `const` generic, so you cannot e.g. pass a variable:

```rust
let name = 1;
<MyStruct as RpcHandler<name, _>>::handle(&x, 0);
// error[E0435]: attempt to use a non-constant value in a constant
```

So you have to still implement the actual dispatching logic, because (as expected) the type/const system cannot infer what values will flow into the program at runtime.

Looking at your code, though, there *are* some things you can put into the traits rather than have to repeat throughout the code. Namely, you can associate RPC handler implementations with their name using an associated constant:

```rust
trait RpcHandler<Req> {
    const NAME: &'static str;
    fn handle(&self, req: Req);
}
```

Each implementation must provide a value for `NAME`. Then, you can use the constant e.g. in the register method:

```rust
fn register_rpc<Req: Default + 'static, T: RpcHandler<Req>>(
    handlers: &mut HandlerMap<T>,
) {
    let wrapper: MyWrapper<Req> = MyWrapper(PhantomData);
    handlers.insert(T::NAME.into(), Box::new(wrapper));
}
```

---

After some discussion in the comments: marker traits/types can be used to achieve something similar to what the `const` generics in the OP were meant to do. Concretely, we can define a marker trait, which does nothing except identify some types as being "methods":

```rust
trait MethodName {}
```

Then, some empty types will implement this trait:

```rust
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

impl MethodName for Foo {}
impl MethodName for Bar {}
```

With this setup, type parameters can be constrained to `MethodName` to solve the problem of multiple implementations of the same trait for the same struct, but for different methods:

```rust
trait RpcHandler<M: MethodName, Req> { ... }

impl RpcHandler<Foo, CommonRequest> for MyStruct { ... }
impl RpcHandler<Bar, CommonRequest> for MyStruct { ... }
```

As a bonus, the `MethodName` trait can also contain a `const NAME: &'static str;`, if the implementation ever needs to reference the method name as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have re-edited my question. Actually I'm not using const generics to do the dispatch. As a trait is only allowed to be implemented ONCE for one type, I actually want to workaround that limitation: I want to implement `RpcHandler<CommonRequest>` for `foo` and `bar` twice on `MyStruct`, so I don't have to write the code of both `foo` and `bar` together, I then can write them in their own implementations.

Comment: And putting `NAME` into trait `RpcHandler` is really a great idea, however, that doesn't solve the problem that `RpcHandler` is still allowed to be implemented only once.

Comment: @KelvinHu I see. Why do you want to implement the traits on the same struct? I assume you want to put some common state in there? You can work around this a couple of ways: 1) reflect different RPC methods in the type system by having different traits for different methods; 2) implement the same `RpcHandler` trait on a newtype wrapper around the struct, e.g. `impl RpcHandler<...> for FooWrapper<MyStruct>`; 3) use marker generics rather than const generics, e.g. `impl RpcHandler<CommonRequest, Foo> for MyStruct`, where `struct Foo;` and `impl IsAMethodName for Foo {}` or similar.

Comment: The 3rd way looks interesting, could you please elaborate that what is `IsAMethodName` used for, and how to associate `struct Foo;` with string `"foo"`?

Comment: @KelvinHu You define a trait like `trait IsAMethodName {}`. It can be empty (or you put the `const NAME: &'static str;` in). Then you have implementors, which are structs, also empty, like `struct Foo; impl IsAMethodName for Foo {}`. Then, `RpcHandler` and other methods can be generic in a type parameter that must be one of the `IsAMethodName` implementors: `trait RpcHandler<TReq, TMethod: IsAMethodName> { ... }`. This way you get something very similar to what you originally wanted with different versions of the same trait for different methods, but replacing the constants with marker types.

Comment: I get your point, this does solve my question, thanks! And it would be great if you could write an example of this solution in your answer section, then people view this question later might be easier to get the solution in the answer than in the comments. :)